# Calculating time based SLA

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am attempting to create a workflow in SPD'13 that will track a SLA for a given task that if it takes longer than 2 days then prompt to send an EMAIL so that it notifies the team they are in breach.  Any thoughts or existing threads would be helpful.  Thank you, Jesse

Answer (score 0):

If the process is a simple as described, then create a workflow that:

- Starts when the item is created.
- Waits 2 days. (Pause for Duration action)
- Checks the value of the "Status" (or other) field. (If condition)
- If status is not what it should be, send an email. (Send an Email action)
- Exits.

[image]

Comment: I will give that a try, I like the simplicity of that.